# Mod-Rewrite: Need help to optimize the Rewrite Rules

Tags: mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Before changing something in my .htaccess links looked like this:

- http://www.domain.tld/index.php
- http://www.domain.tld/index.php?page=start
- http://www.domain.tld/index.php?page=blog

Now I made a .htaccess with this code:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^index.php / [R,L,QSA]
```

Now the the links above looks like this in the browser address bar:

- http://www.domain.tld
- http://www.domain.tld/?page=start
- http://www.domain.tld/?page=blog

That's nearly what I want, but how can I make it look like this?

- http://www.domain.tld
- http://www.domain.tld/start
- http://www.domain.tld/blog

I tried so many different things, but mod_rewriting is not my intensity, yet.
I also want that search engines like Google uses the new URL (SEO).

Comment: I posted the solution as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the solution to change links from `http://www.domain.tld/index.php?page=blog` to `http://www.domain.tld/blog` is:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^\w+$ index.php?page=$0 [L]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} index\.php
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^page=(\w+)$
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ /%1? [R=301,L]
```

and for links like: `http://www.domain.tld/index.php?page=single_news&id=1&headline=This%20Is%20A%Headline`

the solution is:

```
RewriteRule ^blog/(\d+)-([\w-]+)$ index.php?page=single_news&id=$1&headline=$2
```

After using this code, links looks like this: `http://www.domain.tld/blog/2-this-is-a-headline`